# Too many redirect loops in kunena forum

Tags: .htaccess, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am getting error too many redirect loops in kunena forum whenever i am clicking on the category or anything related to kunena forum. This happens if i turn on the sef url option and if i turn off the sef kunena forum is working fine

Answer (score 0):

My last post section has this problem despite me turning off SEO friendly URLS on both Kunena and Joomla AND turning off the Joomla Redirect plugin.

Problem is still occuring. :-(